# TableLayout with pagination

Tags: android, android-layout, pagination, android-tablelayout

I want to implement a `TableLayout` with pagination, showing records of 10 at page 1 and then next 10 on page 2 and so on... I'm using [Table Layout](http://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/how-to-implement-a-paging-feature-in-android/) but I'm not getting the  required result. Using the tutorial, the table just grows horizontally not vertically. How do I change it so that it also grows vertically and then when record size is greater then 10 then shift to next page?

The code:

```
public class Sample extends Activity {
 String companies[] = {"Google","Windows","iPhone","Nokia","Samsung",
         "Google","Windows","iPhone","Nokia","Samsung",
         "Google","Windows","iPhone","Nokia","Samsung","Google","Windows","iPhone","Nokia","Samsung",
         "Google","Windows","iPhone","Nokia","Samsung",
         "Google","Windows","iPhone","Nokia","Samsung"};
 String os[]       =  {"Android","Mango","iOS","Symbian","Bada",
         "Android","Mango","iOS","Symbian","Bada",
         "Android","Mango","iOS","Symbian","Bada","Android","Mango","iOS","Symbian","Bada",
         "Android","Mango","iOS","Symbian","Bada",
         "Android","Mango","iOS","Symbian","Bada"};
 TextView companyTV,valueTV,deviceTv,actionTv,dateTv,timeTv,creditTv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // creates the Pagination Layout
    PaginationLayout paginationLayout = new PaginationLayout(this);
    paginationLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    // creates content only for sample
    TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
    //table.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    table.addView(row);

    TableRow row2 = new TableRow(this);
    row2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    table.addView(row2);
    for (int i=0;i<companies.length;i++)
    {
        deviceTv = new TextView(this);
        deviceTv.setText(companies[i]);
        deviceTv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        deviceTv.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);

        deviceTv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        row2.addView(deviceTv);
        actionTv = new TextView(this);
        actionTv.setText(os[i]);
        actionTv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        actionTv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        actionTv.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        row2.addView(actionTv); // Adding textView to tablerow.
    }

   /* for(int i = 0; i< 50;i++){
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Button " + i);
        if (i%2==0) {
            row.addView(button);
        } else {
            row2.addView(button);
        }
    }*/

    // add the content in pagination
    paginationLayout.addView(table);
    // set pagination layout
    setContentView(paginationLayout);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have already using Table Layout but not getting my required result
>   using this tutorial it just grow horizontally not vertically

For the code on github it appears that using `addView` on the `PaginationLayout` adds that view to a `HorizontalScrollView`. As in your code you're creating a **single** `Tablelayout` to which you add rows, it's normal that your content grows vertically.

You'll most likely need to insert on your own the pages, with something like this:

```
// creates the Pagination Layout
PaginationLayout paginationLayout = new PaginationLayout(this);
LinearLayout wrapper = new Linearlayout(this);
paginationLayout.addView(wrapper);
// now create a TableLayout, if the content is bigger then your intended number of rows
// then insert another Tablelayout and so on
TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
    //table.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
table.addView(row);
TableRow row2 = new TableRow(this);
row2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
table.addView(row2);
wrapper.addView(table); // it will probably don't look good if you don't 
// also setup the proper width with LayoutParams
```

If you continue to add `TableRows` and you see that you've added 10 rows to *table* then create a new `TableLayout` and add that to the *wrapper* `LinearLayout`.

I would advise you to drop that library and implement your own pagination. If you don't what direct interaction from your user(through touching) then it's quite simple to setup a `ViewFlipper`(with two views, two pages through which you'll continue to flip) with two buttons at the bottom to control the pagination. If you also want touch interaction, then use a `ViewPager`(with a bit more work to do).